# Spring - WEB services Problem in Instantiation

Tags: web-services, spring

**HI ALL** 
I am trying to expose spring webservice i am facing one problem My Service Object is not getting initialized 
---------------End point Class--------------

```
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoint;

import com.mt.service.CalculatorService;

public abstract class AbstractCalculatorEndpoint  extends AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoint  {
    protected CalculatorService calculatorService;

    public void setCalcService(CalculatorService calculatorService) {
        this.calculatorService = calculatorService;
    }

    protected abstract Object invokeInternal(Object request) throws Exception;

}
```

-----------**AddNumberEndpoint Class**------------

```
    package com.mt.endpoint;

import com.mt.calculator.schema.AddNumberRequest;

public class AddNumberEndpoint extends AbstractCalculatorEndpoint {
    @Override
    protected Object invokeInternal(Object request) throws Exception {
        AddNumberRequest addNumberRequest = (AddNumberRequest) request;
        if( calculatorService==null )
            System.out.println("------------------- I AM NULL    -------    :(   ");
        return calculatorService.addTwoNumber(addNumberRequest.getFirstNumber(),
                addNumberRequest.getSecondNumber());
    }
}
```

**My Servlet Configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-1.5.xsd">

    <bean id="calculatorService" class="com.mt.service.CalculatorServiceImpl"
        init-method="initialize" />

    <bean id="Calculator"
        class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
        <property name="schema" ref="schema" />
        <property name="portTypeName" value="Calculator" />
        <property name="locationUri" value="/services" />
        <property name="targetNamespace" value="http://www.mt.com/calculator/schema" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="schema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
        <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/calculator.xsd" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="validatingInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
        <property name="xsdSchema" ref="schema" />
        <property name="validateRequest" value="true" />
        <property name="validateResponse" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="loggingInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor" />

    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller"
        contextPath="com.mt.calculator.schema" />
    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="unmarshaller"
        contextPath="com.mt.calculator.schema" />

    <bean id="addNumberEndpoint" class=" com.mt.endpoint.AddNumberEndpoint"
        autowire="byName" />


    <bean name="endpointMapping"
        class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref local="loggingInterceptor" />
                <ref local="validatingInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="{http://www.mt.com/calculator/schema}AddNumberRequest">
                    addNumberEndpoint</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionResolver"
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="defaultFault" value="SERVER" />
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="org.springframework.oxm.ValidationFailureException">CLIENT,Invalid request</prop>
                <prop key="com.mt.service.CalculatorException">SERVER</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Plese Let me know if you need any other information

**Thanks A Lot**

**Thanks A Lot** 
 Previous Exception gone Now I Am Getting 
--------

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">JAXB marshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.Integer" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What's the behavior you're expecting, and what's happening instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are autowiring `addNumberEndpoint` by name so Spring will look for `calcService` to bind to it (because of the setter name) but the id of CalculatorService is `calculatorService`.

Change `setCalcService(...)` to `setCalculatorService(...)` in `AbstractCalculatorEndpoint`

Comment: Thanks A lot I got Solution ... Second time In changed return type of my Service Implementation To **AddNumberResponse** instead Int

Comment: Hi I got this workaround but i want to know in-depth  please provide me links which i should refer **THANKS**